# How to access data from a page on a form hook?

Tags: forms, hooks

I have a page that has a $_GET and I would like to use that value on the form that is used on that page, but I do not know how to pass a variable to that form for use. usually I can just get the data from elsewhere, but the $_GET is NULL when I run it in the form itself.

```
function mymodule_menu() {

   $items = array();

   $items['sample'] = array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'description' => '',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content')
  );
}

function mymodule_page() {
    $variable = $_GET['variable'];
    return theme('mymodule_page', array(
       'form' => drupal_get_form('mymodule_page_form'),
       'variable' => $variable
    ));
}
function mymodule_page_form(){
    var_dump($variable); <-- not defined.
}
```

I tried variable_get and variable_set, but it's not reliable because it seems to hold values for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default variables defined in one function aren't available in any other functions (see [PHP: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)), which is why your variable is undefined in the form function.

You can declare `$variable` as a `global` (see the link above) to make it available in both your functions:

```
function mymodule_page() {
    global $variable;
    $variable = $_GET['variable'];
    return theme('mymodule_page', array(
       'form' => drupal_get_form('mymodule_page_form'),
       'variable' => $variable
    ));
}
function mymodule_page_form(){
    global $variable;
    var_dump($variable);
}
```

But to be honest there's no good reason why `$_GET` would be empty when it reaches your form function, so it might be worth seeing if you can find out why that's happening.

Comment: aha thanks. It turns out something else was happening behind the scenes that made me think the $_GET wasn't showing...